# Loosing my system when i remove USB

Tags: boot, usb

I just bought a laptop on eBay, but Windows won't boot because of some error. I decided to replace the hard drive, and used the one I used to have in my PS4.

On my working computer, I created a bootable Kali USB stick. I booted from the stick on the laptop and chose the "Live USB Persistence" option. It booted, and I got a desktop, but a lot of things didn't work, like opening LeafPad and other simple things. However, those are easy to fix.

The problem I'm having is this: if I remove the flash drive and reboot, I can't boot the laptop. There's nothing on the hard drive. I thought choosing the Persistent session would install Kali, but it isn't. What do I do?

Comment: This site is limited to Ubuntu and its officially-supported derivatives; as such, Kali Linux is considered "off-topic". You can try asking on the **Unix and Linux Stack Exchange**. Also, make sure you've actually *installed* Kali onto the hard drive before you remove the flash drive and restart; it's not clear that you've done this. (that is, you need to select "Install" or "Graphical install" instead of choosing "Live USB persistence")

Answer (score 4):

Well running a Live USB is a single session, it does not save/store data to your HDD or even relate to your currently installed OS. Unless you do an install over the partions storing the actual OS, nothing in your laptops storage will change. So you will always "lose your system" when removing or shutting down from the USB boot.

When you're trying to install Kali from the USB what do you mean it won't install, does it not detect the HDD or is there an error?

Comment: OP says they chose persistence. The issue is they thought persistence meant "install."

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a persistent session doesn't mean Kali will actually install. It just means data on the Live Session will be saved across reboots.

Normally, Live Sessions only save data until a reboot, when all userdata is erased. Normally, you need to install to actually save data. Persistence is somewhere in between. The OS isn't actually installed, but it still saves data to the USB drive.

***Persistence != Installation***

If you want to actually install Kali, you need to go over to [unix.se], since Kali is very off-topic here. Also, please try to ask a question so that it can be read. I had a hard enough time editing it, much less reading it and understanding it the first time round.